# Cannot call value of non-function type 'CLLocationCordinate2d' in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am trying to add two annotations to a map. The map works fine, but when I try to add anotations, I get the above error. Here is the part of code that is relevant to this.

```
//temporary nearby locations list

        //temple tooth
        var templeToothMarker = MKPointAnnotation()
        var templeToothLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 7.294715, longitude: 80.639858)
        templeToothMarker.coordinate(templeToothLocation)
        templeToothMarker.title = "Kandy Dalada Maligawa"
        templeToothMarker.subtitle = "Historic Religious place"

        //botanical gardens

        var botanicalGardenMarker = MKPointAnnotation()
        var botanicalGardenLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 7.294715, longitude: 80.639858)
        botanicalGardenMarker.coordinate(templeToothLocation)
        botanicalGardenMarker.title = "Royal Botanical Gardens"
        botanicalGardenMarker.subtitle = "Historic Religious place"

        //load markers to map
        map.addAnnotations([templeToothMarker, botanicalGardenMarker])
```

The error comes in the

```
templeToothMarker.coordinate(templeToothLocation)
```

and

```
BotanicalGardenMarker.coordinate(templeToothLocation)
```

lines. I am baffled because I am passing the right type of parameter to the `coordinate` method. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Note: in `botanicalGardenMarker.coordinate(templeToothLocation)` you set the garden to the temple's location, not the garden's. Also, use `=` to set the property. It's not a method call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's simple. Coordinate it is a property, not a method. You just need to set it as follow:

```
botanicalGardenMarker.coordinate = botanicalGardenLocation
```

Comment: Hit me with a hammer in the head. If I move, shoot me :( spent 2-3 hours tryng to figure that out

Comment: @toing_toing you might be interested in this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755527/repeating-pin-annotation-on-map/34756033#34756033