# Swift: How do you convert CGPoint to CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, swift

I have the below code, and am trying to add annotation for a longpress on the map. The locationInView is of type 'CGPoint' whereas the 'annotation.coordinate' expects variable of type CLLocationCoordinate2D.
whats the right method to convert CGPoint to CLLocationCoordinate2D ?

```
 func myGestureFunc(thegesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        let pointOfInterest = thegesture.locationInView(self.theMap) //CGPoint


       let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = //expects CLLocationCoordinate2D


        theMap.addAnnotation(annotation)

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34756033/2303865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `convertPoint` along the lines of:

```
let touchPoint = thegesture.locationInView(self.theMap)
let newCoordinate = self.theMap.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView:self.theMap)
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate
theMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Comment: no more option to return coordinates in lated google map sdk , its always returning cgpoint / cgrect what should I do in this case scenario .

Answer (score 0):

Since the convertPoint() method is no longer available, the following code can be used:

```
let coordinate = googleMapView.projection.coordinate(for: point)
```