# Easiest way to get y coordinates during pan swipe gesture in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have managed to get `x and y start coordinates` during a `swipe`:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position :CGPoint = touch.locationInView(view)
        startX = Int(position.x)
        startY = Int(position.y)        
    }
}
```

I need the y coordinates during the swipe as well. I have managed to do this in a very roundabout kind of way with the **`UIPanGestureRecognizer`**.

There must be some way to make it in as few lines as getting the starting coordinates.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Best regards, Niklas

Comment: Do you want to use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` or are you trying to implement this yourself with the `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, etc methods?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/34756033/2303865

Comment: @Carter, I think that `UIPanGestureRecognizer` or `touchesMoved` doesn't really matter as long as I can get the Y coordinates during the swipe.

@LeoDabus, I read through the page you linked but didn't find out how to get the Y coordinates. I'm pretty new to this so it might be there even though i don't see it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for this. It will give you both the x and y coordinates of the swipe. Apple created this specifically for this scenario- it is easier to implement than touchesMoved and tracking everything yourself.

To set up your gesture recognizer:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
self.someDraggableView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

To get the translation (in the callback you set up above):

```
func handlePan(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .Began {
        // When the drag is first recognized, you can get the starting coordinates here
    }

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .Changed {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translationInView(self.view)  
        // Translation has both .x and .y values
    }
}
```

In the `.Changed` part of the callback, your code will be called each time the user moves their finger in the given view. You can get the y coordinate from `translation.y`

You can see more examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503537/swift-uigesturerecogniser-follow-finger).

Comment: **`thankYou!`** That's exactly what I was after. It saved me an embarrassing lot of code lines. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you looking for the method 'touchesMoved'. I am doing this answer on a phone so can't get the format correct